# A proof that Superman does not exist

Tags: logic

If Superman were able and willing to prevent evil, he would do so. If Superman were unable to prevent evil he would be impotent; if he were unwilling to prevent evil, he would be malevolent. Superman does not prevent evil. If Superman exists, he is neither impotent nor malevolent. Therefore, Superman does not exist

1. Read the argument above and encode it into symbolic sentences.

W: Superman is willing to prevent evil.

A: Superman is able to prevent evil.

P: Superman prevents evil.

I: Superman is impotent.

M: Superman is malevolent.

E: Superman exists

***2. Show your process as you work through the logical steps of validating argument.***

Superman were able and willing to prevent evil, he would do so ( A ∧ W ) → P

If Superman were unable to prevent evil he would be impotent   ¬A → I

if he were unwilling to prevent evil, he would be malevolent    ¬ W → M

Superman does not prevent evil  ¬P

If Superman exists, he is neither impotent nor malevolent   E  → (¬ I ∧ ¬ M )

Superman does not exist   ¬ E

------ the rest of the validation i do not understand ----------

¬ ( A ∧ W )

¬ A  ∨ ¬ W

A → ¬ W

A → W

A → M

A→ (M ∨ I)

¬ A → M ∨ I

M ∨ I

¬ ( ¬ I ∧ ¬ M )

¬ E

I found the answers online but i do not understand the other parts of number 2 can someone explain please

Comment: Is this an original problem? Modern approaches use some complicated modal logic to show logical consistency of the premises, see here: http://www.iep.utm.edu/evil-log/

Answer (score 2):

We can use [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)):

1) $\lnot (A \land W) \lor P \equiv \lnot A \lor \lnot W \lor P$

2) $A \lor I$

3) $W \lor M$

4) $\lnot P$

5) $\lnot E \lor (\lnot I \land \lnot M) \equiv (\lnot E \lor \lnot I) \land (\lnot E \lor \lnot M)$

Thus, replace 5) with;

5') $\lnot E \lor \lnot I$

5'') $\lnot E \lor \lnot M$.

Applying resolution to 1), 2), 3) and 4) we get :

6) $I \lor M$.

Applying resolution again with 6), 5') and 5'') we finally get:

> 7) $\lnot E$.

Now we add the negation of the sought conclusion:

> 8) $E$

and we conclude with the empty clause $\square$.

Thus, the conclusion $\lnot E$ is implied by the five premises.

---

The argument "runs" as follows, starting from 5th premise:

- we know that: if Superman exists, he is neither impotent nor malevolent;
- by 4th premise, we have that: Superman does not prevent evil;

so, from 1st premise, by [contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition), we infer that: if Superman does not prevent evil, either he is not able to do or is not willing to do, and thus, by [modus ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens) with the 4th premise:

- either Superman is not able to do or is not willing to do.

Now we argue [by cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination):

- if Superman is not able, then (by 2nd premise): he would be impotent;
- if Superman is not willing, then (by 3rd premise): he would be malevolent.

In both cases, we have a contradiction with the consequent of the 5th premise: Superman is neither impotent nor malevolent.

Thus, by [modus tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens) we conclude with the negation of the antecedent of the 5th premise:

> > Superman does **not** exist.

---

*Comment* : the fact that the argument is [*logically valid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity), does not mean that the conclusion in true.

Only if all the premises are true, we can assert that also the conclusion is so.

But on what ground we assert e.g. 4) : "Superman does not prevent evil" ?

Comment: The question seems to be a standard argument against existence of God, masked as a logic problem about superman.  As you note in your last comment, the issue is not that anyone disagrees with the logic structure, it is the premises.  For example this assumes (i) A God who exists must be capable of everything (does this include the ability to make a logical contradiction?), (ii) Not preventing all evil is malevolent (how does free will fit in here?), (iii) There is some generally-accepted definition of "evil."

Comment: Playing along with the above reasoning though, I suppose one could add a final premise: “If God/superman does not exist then objective notions of evil and malevolence do not exist,” which, if accepted as a valid premise, then creates a logical contradiction with the other premises (which implicitly assume existence of objective notions of evil).

Comment: can some explain this process to someone who has never taken a logic course

Comment: @Bogle - It is an *argument* made of five *premises* and one sought *conclusion*; the "task" is to show/verify if the premises imply the conclusion, i.e. if the argument is *valid*. I've used a *proof procedure* : Resolution, to verify it, and the result is: YES, it is valid.

Comment: Having said that, see the final *Comment* in my answer: the fact that the argument is "logical" does not mean that we have proved that Superman does not exists. What we have proved is : **if** ... (premises) are all true, **then** the conclusion holds.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA    thank you so much i got it

Answer (score 0):

Determine whether this argument, taken from Kalish and Montague [KaMo64], is valid. If Superman were able and willing to prevent evil, he would do so. If Superman were unable to prevent evil, he would be impotent; if he were unwilling to prevent evil, he would be malevolent. Superman does not prevent evil. If Superman exists, he is neither impotent nor malevolent. Therefore, Superman does not exist...